# Add previous/next button as well as multiple images on one Modal

Tags: javascript, html

I have a modal with a image here. However, now I want to add another image inside the modal, and have previous/next button to switch between two images. I tried adding a src there, but I was not able to add previous/next funtion. How do I do that? Thanks!

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 40%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


</head>
<body>

<h2>Modal Example</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content" style="width:740px">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    
    <div align="center"><img src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant#/media/File:African_Bush_Elephant.jpg" width="700" height="560"></div>
    <div align="center"><img src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant#/media/File:Aardvark2_(PSF)_colourised.png" width="700" height="560"></div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Demo's can be find at: [1]https://jsfiddle.net/tinywhui/a5uLgsrp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add them inside the modal as `absolute` positioned elements.

```
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content" style="width:740px">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <img src="left-arrow.svg" />
    <img src="right-arrow.svg" />

    <div align="center"><img src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant#/media/File:African_Bush_Elephant.jpg" width="700" height="560"></div>
    <div align="center"><img src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elephant#/media/File:Aardvark2_(PSF)_colourised.png" width="700" height="560"></div>
  </div>
```

Then, in your javascript, target these elements and add `onclick` functions that hide or show the images within the modal.